# Using cycles materials in video editing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I've set green color for cube in cycles render. Than I added the cube to video editor, but color of cube in grey. I want to use cycles materials in video editing. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are in solid view mode, 
Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel and change the preview mode to  *material* or *rendered*.

[image]

Comment: setting _material_ helped, but _rendered preview_ not. Thank you!

Comment: rendered view will work when the 3d scene have light , and when *Opengl preview* checkbox is not enabled.

Comment: I disabled _Opengl preview_, now I don't see underlying video, only greyness...

Comment: If you disable OpenGL preview you need to enable Film>Transparent

Comment: I'm facing severe performance drop, but It's working! Thank you so much for such fast and helpful responces!